# Which model should use VAR or VECM in the following problem?

Tags: statistics, time-series

I have three variables, all are nonstationary at levels but stationary at first difference I(1) and there exist cointegration among the variable. The problem is, should I go for VAR or VECM model?

Answer (score 0):

since there is statistical evidence of cointegration between the series, you can take advantage of the related series by using a VECM model. Here is an example of an R code, where Xt, Yt and Zt are the series you are analyzing:

```
#VECM model estimation

library(tsDyn)
data<-cbind(Xt,Yt,Zt)
vecm<-VECM(data,lag=1,estim="2OLS")
summary(vecm)
```